# Kernel panic - not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I was trying to install Ubuntu on my windows 8.1 computer. After downloading Ubuntu ISO, I made a partition for Ubuntu on my disk.

I used Easybcd to add Linux at the boot menu. But after restarting my computer it goes directly to the Ubuntu install menu then shows this screen.

What should I do? My priority is to get my computer working again, and hopefully not loose any files as I did not perform a backups.

[image]

Comment: What screen? Did you mean to upload a screenshot?

Comment: I added the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That, my friend, is a Kernel Panic. This type of thing happens when you don't disable FastBoot in Windows 8.1, **before** installing linux.

The only way you're going to be able to restore your PC is with the help of a Windows 8.1 Installation DVD, USB or HDD, or the OEM restore disks.

Windows 8.1 Installation DVD/USB/HDD: Clean Install. Once Ubuntu screws up a PC, you can't clean the installer out without a fresh start, at least not with FastBoot on.

OEM Restore Disks: Well, if it's not obvious yet, you need to factory restore your PC.

Comment: Not a problem at all.